# How do I group by column from table A to another column in table B? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am relatively new to SQL server. I want to know if it is possible to use GROUP BY of one column from TABLE A to GROUP BY another column in Table B... I have tried this block of code... I appreciate all your responses.

```
SELECT SUM(total_likes) 
FROM MSN
GROUP BY 
SELECT * month_ 
FROM POSTINGTABLE;
```

Comment: Please show your database schema, some sample data, and the results you're trying to get. But basically, you just need to learn how to write a JOIN. That's beginning SQL, go back to your tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you aren't saying how to join MSN to POSTINGTABLE.  If your MSN table looks like this:

```
MSNId INT,
total_likes INT,
name VARCHAR(50),
url VARCHAR(255)
...etc.
```

...and your posting table looks like this:

```
MSNId INT,
month_ INT,
year_ INT,
posting_information VARCHAR(255)
...etc.
```

Then your pseudo-query is saying, "add up the total likes from MSN and list this number against each month in POSTINGTABLE".  If there are a total of 100,000 likes in MSN then you would get an answer that looked something like this:

- Jan - 100,000
- Feb - 100,000
- Mar - 100,000
- Apr - 100,000
- etc.

So you need to define how you want to associate the total_likes with each month "bucket".  Your query might end up looking like this:

```
SELECT
    pt.[month_],
    SUM([total_likes]) 
FROM 
    MSN m
    INNER JOIN POSTINGTABLE pt ON pt.SomeId = m.SomeId --Where SomeId is how to join MSN to POSTINGTABLE
GROUP BY 
    pt.[month_]
```

Now your results should look more like this:

- Jan - 30,000
- Feb - 40,000
- Mar - 20,000
- Apr - 10,000
- etc.